# Почему botman и не хочет отвечать?

Tags: php, laravel

Установил все на laravel 8 следуя документации botman, все делал без botman studio

Для тг указал вебхук https://8e40-62-249-129-72.ngrok.io/api/botman/info так же создал ссылку с помощью ngrok

Написал код обрабатывающею данную ссылку

```
    $config = [
        "telegram" => [
            "token" => env('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')
        ]
    ];
    DriverManager::loadDriver(TelegramDriver::class);
    $botman = BotManFactory::create($config);

    $botman->fallback(function($bot) {
        $bot->reply('Sorry ...');
    });

    $botman->listen();
```

При отправках сообщения боту, в консоли ngrok видно новый запрос и ответ 200, но сообщение не приходит
Решил ради интереса отправить пустой post с postman и получил json вот такого характера

```
{
"status": 200,
"messages": [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Sorry ...",
        "attachment": null,
        "additionalParameters": []
    }
]
```

}

Так же есть отдельный запрос для отправки сообщения именно в мой чат с ботом и он отлично работает
Не работает почему-то прослушка сообщений
Возможно кто-то сталкивался с таким, можете, пожалуйста, помочь или намекнуть где может быть проблема

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в env()
Не знаю почему, но phpstore не выдавал ошибку в этом моменте, только когда решил просто $botman пропустить через var_dump и в postman посмотреть, а что он содержит, увидел что в конфиге почему-то не передавался token, хотя стояла просто env() и было все верно
Установил токен вручную и все сразу же заработало :)

Comment: Потому что неправильно использовать функцию `env` в контроллере. Надо создавать конфигурационный файл (или добавлять в один из существующих), а потом получать данные из этого файла функцией `config()`.